# SQL/PHP: Comparing addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do address matches between an array of three-word strings (each an address) and a column ("address") in a SQL Server database. For example I have a string `123 main st` in this array variable and an entry from the column of interest with `123 main st. #A1`. The following are what I'd like my query or script to do.

- find this entry `123 main st. #A1`
- find any entries with strings `1123`, `main`, and `st`
- ignore order
- ignore letter case

What's an efficient and fast way to approach this problem? I'm doing this in the following way. This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE UPPER(address) LIKE UPPER('123%') 
AND UPPER(address) LIKE UPPER('%main%') 
AND UPPER(address) LIKE '%st%';`
```

Comment: Do the three parts of your string need to be in that order, or should it match something like `123 st main`...

Comment: I assume some_table can be very big. One thing that would help is to have the collumn address be indexed. Assuming that is true, the next step would be to get all the "like 123", and then search those for like %main% and like %st%.

Comment: @Frank, what kind of index do you recommend for `LIKE '%foo%'` searches?  Those can [get a bit tricky](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning).

Comment: @pilcrow searches of type like %anthing, will be a bottle neck for sure. As far as I'm concerned, there is no way of indexing a table for them. That's where search engines come in. A search engine can then take your db or web page, take something like "123 main st" and create 3 entries "123", "main", and "st", then you can quicky find them.

Comment: @Frank, yes.  I was just trying to understand what you mean by "one thing that would help is [an index on the column *address*]" if, as I think we agree, "there is no [trivial] way of indexing a table for [those kinds of queries]".

Comment: my idea was that once you had a result set for like '123%', you could then search it for like '%main%' and '%st%'.

Comment: @Michael Fredrickson: no, the order of the words in the strings does not matter. So, `123 st main` should be a match to `123 main st`. I pre-select a much smaller subset (~200-400) of some_table, which is several 10K's rows long. I figured, even if I'm submitting this query 100 times, it will be pretty fast still.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up keeping what I'm doing in the OP. It works for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> What is an efficient and fast way to approach this problem? I

Fix the database. The design enforces bad behavior from the programmer because the datbase designer was simply not cabable to solve this (complex) problem.

> WHERE UPPER(address) LIKE UPPER('123%')

This is - using a non case sensitibve collation - identical to address like '123%' just forcing a slow table scan. Gratulations.

The same for the rest.

Basically go back to database design here- you never will fix this. One approach is to standardize all data WHEN IT IS WRITTEN, so you don't have to do complex queries upon read.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm querying and modifying a DB in a third-party program. What I'm doing is unsupported by the program. I'm not willing to restructure this DB.

Answer (score -1):

Create a CLR function for regular expression matching and use it in SQL Server.